# PMD 4.x generate report not working

Tags: java, pmd

I configured PMD 4.x version plugin in eclipse mars 4.x.

I've tried to generate an XML report by right-clicking the project > PMD> Generate Reports after which this error dialog box appears.

An internal error occurred during: "`RenderReport`". "Compilation unit name must end with .java, or one of the registered Java-like extensions”?